# Qual o tipo de medida utilizada na hora da construção de um site para largura, altura etc...?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, aplicação-web

Qual o tipo de medida utilizada na hora da construção de um site, tipo largura e altura. Se é pixel, porcentagem, ponto, centímetro ?

Comment: Qual é a medida utilizada pelo dispositivo que utilizará para exibir a página?

Answer (score 3):

**Sobre a largura dos sites**, eles normalmente são definidos pelos `@Medias`, Mas não se prenda a números mágicos. Vou te dar vários exemplos do meu ponto de vista.

Primeiro, não existe uma recomendação oficial dos tamanhos de tela e **"BrackPoints"** pela W3C, seja em PX, REM, EM ou CM. 
(As medidas REM e EM são baseadas no font-size padrão do *root-element*, normalmente 16px, logo 1REM = 16px, e o EM e relativo ao REM. aqui tem mais informação sobre isso: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#lengths )

- **em**   font size do elemento
- **ex**   x-height da fonte do elemento
- **ch**   width do "0" (ZERO, U+0030) glifo do fonte do elemento
- **rem**  font size do elemento root
- **vw**   1% da largura do viewport
- **vh**   1% da altura do viewport
- **vmin** 1% do menor dimensão do viewport
- **vmax** 1% do maior dimensão do viewport

**Aqui tem a documentação oficial sobre Media Queries** https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

A Mozilla também não faz referencias aos "BrackPoints" assim como a Google. ***Seguem links oficiais com as boas praticas.***

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/

Também não exite muito consenso entro os *FrameWorks* mais famosos como **Bootstrap**, **Materialize** e **Foundation** por exemplo... Cada um determina uma largura diferente para o Grid e larguras de tela.

> **Bootstrap3** *breakpoints*
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **Bootstrap4** *breakpoints*
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **Materialize** *breakpoints*
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **Foundation** *breakpoints*
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

E para finalizar aqui vai um excelente artigo sobre os tamanhos de tela mais usados atualmente, os dados são de Dezembro de 2017. Artigo: https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/best-screen-size/

**Telas Desktop**

- 1366×768 – 29.25%
- 1920×1080 – 17.34%
- 1440×900 – 7.32%
- 1600×900 – 5.72%
- 1280×800 – 5.27%
- 1280×1024 – 4.51%

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Telas Mobile**

- 360×640 – 41.11%
- 375×667 – 9.58%
- 720×1280 – 5.16%
- 320×568 – 4.55%
- 414×736 – 3.79%
- 320×534 – 3.46%

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Telas Tabler**

- 768×1024 – 57.99%
- 1280×800 – 5.89%
- 600×1024 – 4.6%
- 601×962 – 3.02%
- 800×1280 – 2.94%
- 1024×600 – 2.36%

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fonte:** http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/tablet/worldwide

> **OBS**: Sempre considere o seu público alvo e a experiencia do usuário antes de começar o desenvolvimento!

Answer (score 2):

Tudo depende de qual é a sua necessidade! 
As medidas mais comuns são pixel, porcentagem, EM.

Usamos porcentagem quando queremos desenvolver uma interface que irá se adaptar em outras resoluções, tornando o elemento a qual foi adicionado a porcentagem, flexível com o tamanho da página.

Pixel utilizamos quando queremos algo que seja sempre desse tamanho, pois independentemente do tamanho do dispositivo, o pixel sempre tem o mesmo tamanho.

Deixo abaixo dois artigos que podem ajudar bastante nessa descoberta sobre as unidades!

https://tableless.com.br/unidade-pixels-em-rem/

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html

Espero que tenha ajudado!