# Existe padrão para aplicação de Media Querie?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Estou começando a aprender agora sobre Media Querie e tenho uma duvida que não vi por ai a resposta.

Existe algum padrão na aplicação da media querie ?

É correto ter um arquivo media-querie.css com todas modificações ou o correto seria envolver todo o codigo em blocos de media-queries, sendo que por exemplo, o arquivo de index.css, teria dentro dela um bloco de media-querie em 360px, outro bloco com 960px etc, ambos com todos os codigos css da pagina.

Ou existe ainda, outro padrão ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Existe um padrão sim, chama-se BOOTSTRAP. Já ouviu falar?

Comment: Nesse caso é um framework, e não quero partir pra essa abordagem, quero aplicar algum padrão ao meu projeto que não seja framework, e pelo que vi na documentação do bootstrap, eles seguem um padrão, unico deles de utilizar mixins pra criar os breackpoints. Mas muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual o tipo de medida utilizada na hora da construção de um site para largura, altura etc...?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272494/qual-o-tipo-de-medida-utilizada-na-hora-da-constru%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-site-para-largura-a)

Comment: @Leandro e Bootstrap é padrão de que? Nem o Bootstrap 3 e 4 tem os mesmos valores de Breacking Point nos Media Querie... como que vai ser padrão de alguma coisa. Nem de Bootstrap ele pergunta... tem mais um milhão de Grids por ai, não fiquem presos ao Bootstrap

Comment: Amigo @hugocsl, essa questão que levantei aqui não é uma duplicata da que vc colocou como sugestão, pois lá a pergunta é sobre medidas e minha questão é sobre padrão de criação e aplicação.
E nessa questão de bootstrap ser um padrão, ninguem falou que ele É UM PADRÃO, falei que eles tem o padrão DELES e é isso que estou tentando entender aqui, se EXISTE algum padrão para implementação de media queries ou cada um faz do jeito que achar melhor.

Comment: como um chará seu, vou comentar aqui só porque tem mais 2 leandros comentando aqui eo que o primeiro comentou não tem nada a ver, alias... desconsidere

Comment: @hugocsl Eu quis ser um pouco sarcástico, pois o Bootstrap é que rege aí a arquitetura CSS da maioria dos sites hj. E está impensável hj em dia vc trabalhar profissionalmente sem o auxílio de frameworks.

Comment: Sobre se existe um padrão acho que fica claro na outra pergunta que na há padrão. Sobre o Bootstrap fiz apenas um comentário sobre quem acha que Bootstrap é mandatório e no caso não é, é só mais um Grid como outro qualquer. Sobre os CSSs pode ter uma boa prática em relação a indexação, mas não sobre o tamanho das Media Querie

Comment: faz tempo que não uso o bootstrap... só se for pra codar um painel de admin, fora isso, não é mandatório para layouts

Comment: Leandro obrigado pela resposta sarcastica ... me ajudou muito.
ainda bem que existem pessoas como @hugocsl e o Leandro Ruel pra auxiliarem pessoas que não conhecem nada.

Comment: Leonardo já que vc está começando, não se prenda a "muletas" aproveite e estude como fazer as coisas na mão primeiro. **Metade das perguntas de Bootstrap aqui no site é de gente que da crtl+c e ctrl+v e depois não consegue fazer o que quer pq não tem ideia do que está fazendo**. Começa com a base, e não com modelo prontos que vc não entende. É só uma dica se vc pretende levar os estudos a diante.

Comment: Cara o q quero desde o começo dizer é que querendo ou não vc TERÁ que aprender lidar com Bootstrap, Materialize, Bulma, etc... Qualquer empresa que deseje ter produtividade em desenvolvimento de layouts os utilizam. Como o rapaz disse ali em cima em o Bootstrap não ser mandatório, não sou e nem ele que decide isso é o mercado.

Comment: @Leandro Mandatório ou não você não conseguira utilizar uma ferramenta produtivamente a menos que perceba as coisas que ela está fazendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **OOCSS**

Pelo pouco que sei, a convenção do OOCSS (CSS Orientado a Objeto) fala que o melhor é criar um biblioteca com os componentes CSSs separados.

Portanto, de forma exemplar, deveria-se criar uma folha de estilo separada para cada componente de um projeto, como botões, navbar, typografia, etc...

**Exemplo gráfico:**

```
root
|
+-- index.html
|
+-- css/main.css; buttons.css; navbar.css; typography.css...
|
+-- js/
```

### Situação fictícia com botões

Dessa maneira, se a tua necessidade fosse aplicar breakpoints (media queries) em botões, criaria-se um arquivo buttons.css que conteria as regras para os variados tamanhos dos botões.

**Como ficaria a folha de estilo de um componente para botões:**

```
.btn {
    width: x;
}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 682px;){
        .btn-y {
            width: y;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px;){
        .btn-z {
            width: z;
        }
    }
```

## Conclusão

Modularize o seu CSS, de forma que cada componente tenha seu próprio CSS. Assim, dentro de cada folha de estilo utilize os breakpoints relativos ao determinado componente.

Ainda sobre folhas de estilos, perceba que falei sobre OOCSS de forma rasa, por isso recomendo que pesquise sobre o assunto.

Além do mais, não leve em conta o comentário daqueles que falam para usar Bootstrap, afinal, não tem nem relação com sua dúvida.

*Ps: Tenho dificuldade de me expressar. Por isso, se ainda tiver dúvida, comenta.*

**Edit 1:** Essa situação que mencionei, só se aplica em fase de desenvolvimento. Portanto, você teria que usar algo como pré-processadores para combinar tudo, ao finalizar o desenvolvimento.

**Edit 2:** O @hugocsl trouxe este [link](https://css-tricks.com/one-two-three/) que explica como se comportar, na hora de publicar.

Comment: Jovem essa metodologia vários CSSs só é valida para ambiente de desenvolvimento, pois facilita a manutenção etc, mas na hora de publicar a prática é minificar tudo em um CSS só, assim se evita um número excessivo de requisições e diminui o tempo de resposta da página. Múltiplos CSSs tb não é boa pratica para sites, assim como o uso de @imports de folhas de estilo. Então o melhor é só um CSS? Não :) essa pergunta é baseada em opiniões ao meu ver. Links https://css-tricks.com/one-two-three/ e  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files

Comment: E só pra falar que eu não sou totalmente contro mais de um CSS a opcão de um CSS para "Above the Fold" e outro para "Under the Fold" é algo que me agrada!

Comment: Sim, @hugocsl , não é correto fazer demasiadas requisições. E, como CSS Tricks e você fala, a metodologia pode ser boa somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento (algo que eu não mencionei).

No entanto, minha resposta ainda seria correta, se a situação dele é em development?
Será que cabe um 'edit' com o link para o CSS Tricks e outro para explicar essa parada de deploy e development?

Comment: Sim jovem, fique a vontade para melhorar a sua resposta, a propósito, nem foi eu que te negativei, só dei minha opinião sobre o assunto...

Answer (score 1):

vou te dar uma resposta baseado no que faço em meus projetos, na verdade eu não especifico um padrão específico de tamanho nas minhas media queries, o que faço é desenvolver um layout o mais fluído possível com ajuda de algumas tecnologias CSS (obrigado flexbox), e nos meus testes, uso um emulador de responsividade, quando o layout alcançar uma determinada largura e meu layout quebra nesse ponto, eu insiro um breakpoint naquela largura, Ex: tenho um slider e em tamanho desktop se comporta normalmente mostrando 3 imagens, quando a largura esta em 320px o slider "quebra" em 3 linhas, introduzo um breakpoint `@media all and (max-width: 320px){}` e ali coloco as regras para que meu slider fique mostrando apenas uma imagem por vez.