# CSS responsivo não é lido pelo site

Tags: css

O arquivo *responsive.css* não está sendo lido pelo meu site.

Estou chamando assim:

```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
```

Dentro dele há o seguinte código:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.right-side { width: 100%; }}
```

No caso, o **right-side** está definido como **50%**.

O qual não está sendo aplicado quando eu emulo o navegador na versão mobile.
Galaxy S5 (360*640)

O que pode ser?

Comment: Já usou a ferramenta de dev do seu navegador (**[F12]**) pra verificar se o script foi carregado corretamete e se nenhum outro *style* está conflitando com a regra? Ainda pode ser que o `@media` está adequado pra resolução que está testando

Comment: Sim, é aqui que não chama. Se eu colocar o caminho do arquivo diretamente no navegador, ele abre normalmente. Qual resoluções você indica usar no **@media**?

Comment: As do *bootstrap* me parecem boas e bem aceitas: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: Nesse projeto não usarei Bootstrap. Quais vocês costuma usar?

Comment: Não sei como está a navegação do site nem as pastas, mas se não estiver carregando o `css`, talvez possa tentar forçar buscar da raiz do site com a barra: `href="/css/responsive.css"`

Comment: Entendi, mas se olhar no link, vai ver que tem as resoluções usadas no *bootstrap*: Extra small devices Phones (<768px), Small devices Tablets (≥768px), Medium devices Desktops (≥992px), Large devices Desktops (≥1200px). Tento copiar as mesmas :)

Comment: Vc coloca o seu código completo HTML/CSS inclusive com a `<head>` da página que ajuda. Sobre as larguras de tela acho que essa resposta pode te ajudar. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272494/qual-o-tipo-de-medida-utilizada-na-hora-da-constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-site-para-largura-a/272537#272537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionou as seguintes meta tags no `<head>`?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Eu não estava chamando. Agora está funcionando.