# Não consigo entender a diferença entre porcentagem e px no CSS

Tags: css, header

Bom dia! Eu estou criando um simples menu (header), mas não consigo entender quando utilizo o px ou a porcentagem.
Por exemplo: esse foi o header que eu criei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu coloquei as  seguintes configurações nela:

```
.header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 1919px;
height: 80px;
background: #f13c78;
```

No caso eu quero que esse menu funcione no tablet e no celular tambem, então nao sei se está certo usar  px  ali ou se devo usar porcentagem, também não sei se a resolução ali está certa ou se está tudo errado.. por favor ajudem, eu sei que é algo básico mas eu não estou conseguindo entender de forma alguma ;(

Acho que não ficou bem explicado mas o meu problema é: Eu não sei quando usar o px ou a porcentagem ali no ''width'' e no ''height'' eu quero que o meu header funcione tanto no pc quanto no tablet, celular etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: pronto corrigi, deu para entender agora?

Comment: Quando for utilizar _porcentagem_, sempre olhe para o _elemento pai_, pois ele será a referência, já que a porcentagem obrigatoriamente deve se referir ao valor de alguma coisa, ou seja, _tantos porcento de quanto?_. Já o `px` é um valor fixo que não depende de nada.

Comment: Um ex.: se eu colocar uma div dentro de uma div e definir 50% de largura na div filha, ela então terá a metade da largura da div mãe.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela resposta! Mas e quando eu for criar um header, por exemplo? vou ter que usar obrigatoriamente o px? e então em um sub header utilizo a porcentagem? não entendi bem

Comment: Não tem essa de "obrigatório". Vc usa o que faz mais sentido, dependendo do que precisa fazer. Quer o tamanho fixo, use `px`, quer relativo, use porcentagem (em linhas gerais, claro, lembrando que ainda tem o `em`, `rem`, etc). Não tem fórmula pronta, tudo depende de cada caso. Veja mais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14217/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106962/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272537/112052

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende muito do que você quer fazer e da pessoa que está a fazer. É uma discussão longa que já foi batida muitas vezes. As `percentagens` são vantajosas porque é a percentagem do ecran ou (em 99% dos casos)do parent(pai) do elemento, ou seja é uma unidade de medida dinâmica, o que faz com que seja mais responsive, os `PX` no meu entender só se devem usar para pequenas coisas como margen, paddigs e afins, ainda há quem use os `REM` para substituir `percentagens/PX`. Você deve entender que as `%` são dinâmicas e se adequam/adaptam ao elemento pai, os `PX` são estaticos seja qual for o tamanho do ecra o elemento vai ter sempre o mesmo tamanho em `PX`. Pode ler mais um pouco sobre isso em https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html